# Microsoft Graph putting null to /users/:id/photo/$value causing 500

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the microsoft graph node.js sdk, making an app-only request to PUT to `/users/f580eac0-9ece-413a-a26f-7964df1f2025/photo/$value`, and I get the following:

```
{ statusCode: 500,
  code: 'ErrorInternalServerError',
  message: 'Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: userPrincipalName',
  requestId: 'a5f0429d-ad3f-4f83-9e50-f540e5c8f9b8',
  date: 2017-07-20T23:17:17.000Z,
  body:
   { code: 'ErrorInternalServerError',
     message: 'Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: userPrincipalName',
     innerError:
      { 'request-id': 'a5f0429d-ad3f-4f83-9e50-f540e5c8f9b8',
        date: '2017-07-20T23:17:17' } } }
```

How can I clear the photo for this user?

Comment: Just to confirm, you have `User.ReadWrite.All` as a scope and `f580eac0-9ece-413a-a26f-7964df1f2025` is a value user ID in your directory?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately deleting a photo (or setting to null) is not supported currently.  This is something that is being worked on, but I don't have a clear ETA and it may be some time before it's available.

The only (nasty) workaround I'm aware of is to PUT a 1x1 transparent photo.

Hope this helps,